Downloading Cloudinary File in Laravel
Please I have two questions to ask;
The first one is how can I download cloudinary file in laravel?
I have tried every methods chatGPT provided. It downloads the file(pdf), But the file is of size 0 bit and I can't open it.
This
public function downloadPdf($token){
  $user = User::where('info_token', $token)->first();
  $filePath=$user->cv_URL;
  $filename='my_cv.pdf';
     // Fetch the PDF file content from the Cloudinary URL
    $response = Http::get($filePath);

    // Check if the response is successful
    if (!$response->successful()) {
        abort(500, 'Failed to fetch PDF file from Cloudinary');
    }

    // Set the appropriate headers for the file download
    return response($response->body())
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        ->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  }
``` is how I am trying to get it.


The second issue is that.
I'm trying to send an email, but the email doesn't use the email I provided as (from email) but uses the name I provided as (from name) and the email I used to which is in .env file.
Please how can I resolve it?

This is the code;

public function sendMail(Request $request,$token){
$user = User::where('info_token', $token)->first();
$mailData=[
'title'=>$request->subject,
'body'=>$request->body
];
$mail = new ContactMail($mailData);
$mail->from($request->email, $request->lastName);
// Send the email
Mail::to($user->email)->send($mail);
return response()->json(['message' => 'Email sent successfully.', 'error' => false]);
}


It uses the name I provided here "$mail->from($request->email, $request->lastName)" but not the email

I wan you to please help me out.


Out of interest, what happens when you try to download a non-Cloudinary asset? Also, you're probably better off posting a separate thread for each question

One thing to be aware of is that Cloudinary customers with a free account can’t deliver files in the PDF format by default. This is a security measure. If you want to deliver PDF files you will need to open a ticket with support to get that feature enabled.
More info here: https://cloudinary.com/blog/uploading_managing_and_delivering_pdfs
